# What I should to do on the server side, for collect minidumps from crashpad library?

Tags: c++, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I integrated google crashpad library into my application. Everything works fine, but now I want to collect crash dumps on my own server.
As I understand from the documentation, I can set "url" parameter in `CrashpadClient::StartHandler()` API and `crash_handler` will be upload `minidump` int my server.
But I do not find any information what I should to do on the server-side for received this dumps.
I created a simple `php` script on the server:

```
<?php error_log(var_export($_GET, true)); ?>
```

and pointed it in "url" parameter.

And in server logs found the following strings:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: array (
mod_fcgid: stderr:   'product' => 'My Product',
mod_fcgid: stderr:   'version' => '1.0.0',
mod_fcgid: stderr:   'guid' => '236ac3bd-918b-4daa-948c-3a564509e3d3',
mod_fcgid: stderr: )
```

What I should do with it next and how to organize `minidumps` collection on the server-side?

Answer (score 2):

On your server you'll need to invoke `minidump_stackwalk` which is a Breakpad tool for analyzing minidump crash files.

Here's the information you get if you invoke `minidump_stackwalk` with no arguments on MacOS:

```
Usage: minidump_stackwalk [options] <minidump-file> [symbol-path ...]

Output a stack trace for the provided minidump

Options:

  -m         Output in machine-readable format
  -s         Output stack contents
```

You'll need to invoke `minidump_stackwalk` with a path to a minidump file and a directory that contains the corresponding symbols.

Symbols are generated via the Breakpad tools `dump_syms` and `symupload`. On your server you'll also need to expose a way to upload these symbols so that they are accessible to `minidump_stackwalk`. It's important to note that the symbols folder needs to be laid out on disk in a very specific format otherwise `minidump_stackwalk` will not unwind the call stack in the minidump. The directory structure for all sym files inside the symbols folder much match the following path structure `/MODULE_NAME/MODULE_ID/MODULE_NAME.sym`.

More information on how to use `minidump_stackwalk` can be found [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/crashpad/building/#symbolicating).

More information on how to use `dump_syms` and `symupload` can be found [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/crashpad/building/#generating-symbols) and [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/crashpad/building/#uploading-symbols).

Answer (score 0):

I used this example for creating a crashdump server: https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/master/tools/crash_server.py